# Code Works On Local Machine But Not On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

***Note I am not the original author of this syntax, I found 
it from another stackoverflow user and it worked in my instance***

I am running `IIS 7.5` and hosting this `asp.net` page.  I am using my `Global sax` to catch any errors and write to text file for later review (working on implementing `Elmah` but that is a story for another day).  On IIS, this is a `Windows Server 2008` machine, this code throws no errors, the page loads but none of the data sources have been populated.  On my local machine, as well as 3 other machines (all non-server) the code executes as it should.  What prevents this from executing on our server (production machine)?
**GlobalAsax**

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
  Server.ClearError();
  if (CurrentException != null)
  {
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("ErrorLog.txt")))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(CurrentException.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
}
```

And this is my C# --

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadDataAsync().ToPageAsyncTask());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { throw ex;  }
}
public Task LoadDataAsync()
{
var t1 = ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(connectionString, "Select Top 10 * from uno");
var t2 = ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(connectionString, "Select Top 10 * from tres");
var t3 = ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(connectionString, "RunStoredProcedure");
return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { t1, t2, t3 }, _ =>
{
    try
    {
        this.ddluno.DataSource = t1.Result;
        this.ddluno.DataBind();
        ddltopperformers.DataSource = t2.Result;
        ddltopperformers.DataBind();
        this.gridall.DataSource = t3.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
});
}
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSet> ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(string connectionString, string sqlQuery)
{
SqlConnection _sqlDatabaseConnection;
SqlCommand _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
SqlParameter _sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
SqlDataAdapter _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
StringBuilder _sqlQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();

return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
() =>
{
    try
    {
        _sqlDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _sqlDatabaseConnection);
        _sqlDatabaseConnection.Open();
        _sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        _dataSet = new DataSet();
        _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqlCommand);
        _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet, "Data");
        _sqlDatabaseConnection.Close();
        _sqlCommand.Dispose();
        _sqlDataAdapter.Dispose();
        return _dataSet;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
});
}

public static class PageAsyncTaskGenerator
{
    public static PageAsyncTask ToPageAsyncTask(this Task task, Action<IAsyncResult> onTimeout = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Func<Task> func = () => task;
            return new PageAsyncTask(
                (sender, e, cb, extraData) => func.BeginInvoke(cb, extraData),
                ar => func.EndInvoke(ar).Wait(),
                ar =>
                {
                    if (onTimeout != null)
                    {
                        onTimeout(ar);
                    }
                },
                null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { throw exception; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the connection string I use, what should I change so it works on my IIS?

```
private string connectionString = "Data Source=OnFleet;Initial Catalog=TestForCode;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

**EDIT 2**
Trying to use `webconfig` to create the connection, this is my string but still not connecting.  Am I missing the obvious (again)?

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=OnFleet;Initial Catalog=TestForCode;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;;User ID=IISUser;Password=nottellingSO" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: have you changed a connection string?

Comment: @Khazratbek - no the connection string is the exact same.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Is my question improperly worded or answered elsewhere?

Comment: LocalMachine and IIS in your case is not the same, right? So you have to change your connection string. Try to use breakpoints and debug your code.

Comment: @Khazratbek - I updated my post to show my connection string.  How would I need to alter it so that it works on my IIS machine?

Comment: If you have static IP, you may appoint this. If not, you have to have some machine with static IP and copy your database there, or install it to IIS

Comment: datasource should be the IP or server name, please check if what you supplied is correct

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi - the data in my private string connectionString is accurate database information.  I am debugging now to see if possibly IIS_USERS is not authorized to that server/database and I need to pass in a username/password with my connection string.

Comment: @FightingApesInATub first take a look in IIS on what is the authentication type used in the published site. And dig down if the users for that authentication type doesnt have roles to accesss the db server

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi - Forms Authentication and Anonymous Authentication are the two that are Enabled in IIS

Comment: @FightingApesInATub you have extra semicolon before the user ID, and one thing please mask user credentials because this is confidential. Try to disable that authentication types and enable anonymous and check if it works. For testing only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to impersonate the execution on IIS by providing a valid user account.
Localy you are using your logged user account (used in your Sql Connetion too) but in your published web site you are not in the same context because it is executed by the AppPool (without any right on your SQL Server).
Try adding this line in your web.config file :

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="validAccount@mydomain" password="bar"/>
</system.web>
```

btw, this account need to be in the IIS_IUSRS security group to have the minimum rights on folders (avoid using an admin account) and to be a valide user account in the SQL Server.

*Edit: You can also use an Sql account (created in SQL Server with some right on target DB)

```
Data Source=OnFleet;Initial Catalog=TestForCode;User id=validSqlAccount;Password=myPsw;
```

Comment: Can't I also do it using the connectionStrings from my webconfig?

Comment: Not that way, you cannot use Windows account auth in SqlConnetionString but can use an SQL Account yes.

Comment: In your connection string you should either have `Integrated Security=True` OR `id=xxx;password=xxx;` but not both. When you specify `Integrated Security=True`, it uses the current windows user and ignores any supplied id and password altogether. There are no errors when specifying both but it's confuses people. Since you appear to have got windows authentication working you should remove the `id=xxx;password=ccc;` part